# How to handle a transaction timeout in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to handle a TransactionTimeout, but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried to set a `try catch` inside my method, but it does not work.

```
    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionTimeout(value = 5, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    public boolean setInfo(Info info) {
        boolean control = true;
        while(control) {};

        return false;
    }
```

I would like to set an action in the event that this fails.

Comment: If you are using spring framework, it must be @Transactional annotation. It has timeout capability.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using Spring... It's the custom...

Comment: not sure whether I understand this completely..
If this helps - you can consider using ExecutorService. Executor's submit method will provide a 'Future' that supports timeout and it will throw TimeoutException with which you will be able to set the action accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if it can work or not, but I need to use ```@TransactionTimeout```